# Resets Sends Reset

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-red

When using this node.

node-red-contrib-queue-gate.

And reset is sent on the msg.payload using control topic it works 100%. And no output is given by the q-gate node. But when reset is sent twice by mistake. the output of the node is reset on the msg.payload.
Is it not supposed to use the control topic as controls and not output the control topic? If I'm using it wrong please indicate what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You will do better raising this as an issue with the node directly on GitHub (https://github.com/drmibell/node-red-contrib-queue-gate/issues)

Comment: I did.... 2days no reply.

Comment: In that case you might as well start reading the code